# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, web-config

I just published my ASP.NET Website on IIS and have already configured it to be working, everything is running smoothly.

Except.. I can't accept the App_Data file where all my database information is stored. That might not be the only folder that i can't access but maybe possibly App_Code too? Where i place all my Data Access Object classes (CRUD).

I searched high and low on blogs, articles and stackoverflow but i still can't find the solution to accessing the folders.

I also read that by default certain file extensions are being blocked by IIS.

Is there a possible way to solve this?

Web.config

[image: webconfig]

Error

[image: Error]

I read that changing (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB to something else might work?

I'm not sure exactly..

Appreciate any help please.. I'm relatively new to IIS and this is my first published website running on localhost.